# How to access Builder() of a JPA entity using Lombok with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, lombok

This is my entity class. I have used @Builder annotation. The Lombok version is 1.16.16

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String author;

}
```

Now, when I am trying to call the Builder() method in the main class, it is not getting resolved.

```
Stream.of("Post one", "Post two").forEach(
                title -> this.booksList.save(Book.Builder().title(title).author("author of " + title).build())
            );
```

This is being shown.

> The method Builder() is undefined for the type Book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by Book b = new Book.builder()
               .id(id).name(name).author("author of " + title).build();

May be you are trying to use title, which you haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields are:

```
private Long id
private String name
private String author
```

and in your builder constructor you put `Book.Builder().title(title)`, **the title is missing** in the Book entity, a part "builder()" has to start with lowercase.

**EDIT:**

Ok, then you can remove `@AllArgsConstructor, @NoArgsConstructor, @RequiredArgsConstructor` and test it.

Comment: Correcting those does not change anything.